# Incorrect output/index with a "2D" array

Tags: java

I have this java code that's supposed to give you the sum of hours worked per employee per week then sort the total hours in a descending order. The problem is that when it compiles, the employee ID's are messed up.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks

```
static void list(Object[] a, Object n) {

    int empID = Arrays.binarySearch(a, n);
        System.out.println("Employee " + empID + " :  " + n);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] hours = new int[][]{
            {2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 9},
            {3,7, 5, 4, 3, 5, 9, 4},
            {12, 5, 9, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2},
            {4, 9, 3, 3, 5, 9, 4, 10},
            {5, 3, 5, 9, 3, 6, 3, 8},
            {6, 3, 4, 4, 6, 3, 14, 4},
            {7, 3, 7, 4, 8, 3, 5, 9},
            {8, 6, 3, 5, 9, 8, 7, 9}};

    Integer[] totalHours = new Integer[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j < 8; j++) {
        sum += hours[i][j];
        totalHours[i] = sum;
    }

}


    Integer[] sorted;

    sorted = new Integer[totalHours.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < totalHours.length; i++) {
            sorted[i] = totalHours[i];
        }

    Arrays.sort(sorted, Collections.reverseOrder());
        for (int i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {

        }   

        for (int i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
            list(totalHours, sorted[i]);
        }

}
```

Comment: Because you aren't storing the employeeId anywhere. It appears like you tried to make it the index, but when you sort the index changes.

Comment: Is there any way I can preserve the original index and use that instead?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to create an `Object` type (and sort that `Object` type) to preserve it.

Comment: How would I go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would create an `Employee` class including an ID and hours worked. Once you have a list of employees you can happily search, sort, total etc.

For example:

```
class Employee {
    private final int id;
    private int[] hours;
    public int getTotalHours() {
        return Arrays.stream(hours).sum();
    }
}

List<Employee> employees;
Collections.sort(employees, (e1, e2) -> e1.getTotalHours() - e2.getTotalHours());
```

If for some reason you particularly don't want to create an `Employee` class and you want to continue to use the id as an index into the hours array, then you could create a separate array of the employee ids and sort that by total hours.

```
int[] employees = new int[hours.length];
for (int i = 0; i < hours.length; i++)
    employees[i] = i;
Arrays.sort(employees, (e1, e2) -> getTotalHours(e1) - getTotalHours(e2));
```

You would then have a sorted array of employee ids which are also indexes into your `hours` array.

But, frankly, this is a pretty hacky way to do it so create the Employee class if you can.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm working on the implementation of the solution now. I will post the corrected code once I'm done